# Is there a way to deduce Z-Transform initial and final value theorems from Laplace Transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing, control-theory, z-transform

Given that Laplace Transform and Z-Transform are closely related, I wonder if there's a way to deduce Z-Transform final value theorem:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f[n] = \lim_{z \rightarrow 1}(1-z^{-1}) F(z)$$

from Laplace Transform final value:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f(t) = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} sF(s)$$

and Z-Transform initial value theorem:

$$f[0] = \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} F(z)$$

from Laplace-Transform initial value theorem:

$$f(0) = \lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} sF(s)$$

Comment: You can insert the definition of $s$ in $z$ domain